# is there a way to return a response first but still does something else after the response? django

Tags: python, django, return, response

I want to return a response in django view first then does something after the response.

Let's say I have something like this as example.....

```
class Res(View):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.POST
        new_obj = Model.objects.create(name=data.['name'])

        #  what is below does not have to be done RIGHT AWAY, can be done after a response is made
        another_obj = Another()
        another_obj.name = new_obj.name
        another_obj.field = new_obj.field
        another_obj.save()

        # some other looping and a few other new models to save

        return JsonResponse({'status': True})
```

So I am wondering if there is a chance to return the response first?  What's above is an example of what I mean.

I am not sure if this can be done in django, if possible, can someone let me know who this can be done

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use celery tasks for this.

Comment: Yes, celery is one excellent way to do it. Read about it here: https://realpython.com/blog/python/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/

Comment: thx thx, I will try this out soon and see how it works.

Comment: by just reading it, I can kind of thinking that I will make what needs to be delayed into a function then `.delay` it, but I don't really get when does it know to call it though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's more of a Python than Django question. As the comments have pointed out, you could implement some sort of asynchronous queue like Celery however this may be a bit of an overkill for your use case.

Consider using plain [Python threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects) instead:

```
from threading import Thread


def create_another_obj(name, field):
        another_obj = Another()
        another_obj.name = name
        another_obj.field = field
        another_obj.save()

class Res(View):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.POST
        new_obj = Model.objects.create(name=data['name'])

        # start another thread to do some work, this is non-blocking
        # and therefore the JsonResponse will be returned while it is
        # running!
        thread = Thread(
                     target=create_another_obj,
                     args=(new_obj.name, new_obj.field),
                 )
        thread.start()

        return JsonResponse({'status': True})
```

The idea here is to extract the code which you want to run asynchronously into functions and run them in a thread.

Comment: I just saw your response, that seems to be a good idea, which I would give it a try.  Does the `thread(target=)` has to be a function?

Other than using in this kind of case, there are other cases such as passing objects to S3 which does not require it to be done in order for `JsonResponse` done.

Comment: Yes, `target` has to be a function, [check out the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects). You can also create a class in which you inherit from `Thread` and override `run()`.